# Java programming issue

Tags: java, elementary-functions

Can anyone help me to solve this issue . I do not understand where I can put the number of the area. Also what exactly this expression mean:

```
in.nextInt();
```

Here is the program:

> Write a Java program that reads an integer value representing the side
>   of a square shape and prints out the square’s area and perimeter. Use
>   proper labels for all outputs and comment your code properly.

Comment: Java !== JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

First of all, 
`in.nextInt();` command means that the programme will allow the user to input an integer number from keyboard. 
Where as `in` means the Scanner type variable you have declared above your code. As for your code, it probably is :

`Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);`

and `nextInt();` means that the allowed input, must be of integer type.

You can also give a prompt text from the input by :

```
int x;
System.out.print("Enter Length : ");
x=in.nextInt();
```

Where variable `x` is an integer and it will assign the input value by the user.

When the programme is executed, it would show this on console :

> Enter Length :

Hope that works for you, and I guess using `x` you can pretty much write the rest of your code by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

That line of code is just allowing a user to input an Integer. You need to use Scanner or BufferedReader to read the input.